# How to use transactions with Spring/MyBatis? Best practice?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, transactions, mybatis

I am trying to use transactions with MyBatis and Spring and was wondering if there is a best practice on how to achieve this? Any hints or thoughts are appreciated.

My application wil be running in a tomcat container against a MySQL database.

Answer (score 1):

You want to take a look at the @Transactional annotation [docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html)
In terms of best practices it is a mixture of database transactions and spring. Look at where you need to roll back your data, do you need JTA, etc.

Example class

```
@Transactional
public class DefaultFooService implements FooService {

   Foo getFoo(String fooName);
}
```

Example xml

```
<!-- this is the service object that we want to make transactional -->
<bean id="fooService" class="x.y.service.DefaultFooService"/>
<!-- enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->         <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>

<!-- a PlatformTransactionManager is still required -->
<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
<!-- (this dependency is defined somewhere else) -->
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```